# Trying to upload audio to AWS S3 bucket using method(AWSS3TransferUtility). Pod - AWSS3

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, awss3transfermanager

We are trying to upload audio to AWS S3 bucket using method(AWSS3TransferUtility). Pod - AWSS3. We are getting below error.

Error description:

> Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={Server=AmazonS3, Transfer-Encoding=Identity, Connection=close, Content-Type=application/xml, Date=Fri, 06 Sep 2021 04:43:50 GMT, x-amz-request-id=VH53PCCWA529FDRC, x-amz-id-2=4uZoqJj+TJ93WUBSnrC889CAj3gkGGw/V6iJjhrVjB2+ZygTflGcPAV+amfxmeBGeGHHVXv3nHk=}

```
func uploadFile(withImage image: UIImage) {

    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:AWSRegionType.USEast2,

                                                            identityPoolId:"us-east-2:fe41c293-df49-49a4-886d-094f2cd8d0fd")

    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.USEast2, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)

    let tuConf = AWSS3TransferUtilityConfiguration()

    AWSS3TransferUtility.register(

        with: configuration!,

        transferUtilityConfiguration: tuConf,

        forKey: "transfer-utility-with-advanced-options"

    )

    let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.s3TransferUtility(forKey: "transfer-utility-with-advanced-options")

    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

    let s3BucketName = "testingimageupload"

    let data: Data = image.pngData()!

    let remoteName = generateRandomStringWithLength(length: 12)+"."+"png"

    print("REMOTE NAME : ",remoteName)

    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()

    expression.setValue("public-read", forRequestHeader: "x-amz-acl")

    expression.progressBlock = { (task, progress) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            // Update a progress bar

        })

    }

    var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock?

    completionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            

        })

    }

    transferUtility!.uploadData(data, bucket: s3BucketName, key: "private/Abhay/" + remoteName, contentType: "image/"+"png", expression: expression, completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith { (task) -> Any? in

        if let error = task.error {

            print("Error : \(error.localizedDescription)")

        }

        

        if task.result != nil {

            let url = AWSS3.default().configuration.endpoint.url

            let publicURL = url?.appendingPathComponent(s3BucketName).appendingPathComponent(remoteName)

            if let absoluteString = publicURL?.absoluteString {

                // Set image with URL

                print("Image URL : ",absoluteString)

            }

        }

        return nil

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Prerequisite : Setup AWS Amplify CLI.

### 1. Project initialisation.

---

`amplify init`: Setup AWS Amplify locally & remote.

### Note: amplify init command not found

```
1)`npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli` - ### install the Amplify CLI ###
2)`curl -sL https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-cli/install | bash && $SHELL` ### configured $Path correctly ###
3)`amplify init` ###Try Amplify init###
```

`Amplify Demo project or click enter for the default name` : Enter a name for the project

`Dev or click enter for the default name` :  Enter a name for the Environment

`Choose Visual Studio Code` : Choose your default Editor

`iOS` : Choose the type of app that you’re building

`yes` : Do you want to use an AWS Profile?

### 2. Project Storage setup

`amplify add storage` : Add storage

`Content(Images, audio, video, etc.)` : Select the below mentioned services

`yes` : (Amazon Cognito) Do you want to add auth now?

`No`: Do you want to configure advanced settings?

`bucket name or click enter for the default name` : Please provide bucket name

`Auth users only or Auth and guest users` : Who should have access

`create/update , read , delete.` : What kind of access do you want for Authenticated users?

`create/update , read , delete.`: What kind of access do you want for guest users?

`No` : Do you want add a lama trigger for your S3 Bucket?

### 3. Push - Amplify configuration to backend

`amplify push` : Amplify Push

`Yes`:  are you sure you want to continue ?

### Pod install

```
target ‘ProjectName do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Amplify'
  pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSS3StoragePlugin'
  pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSCognitoAuthPlugin'
end
```

### Code: ViewController.swift

```
import Amplify
import AmplifyPlugins

func configureAmplify() {
        do {
            try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
            try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSS3StoragePlugin())
            try Amplify.configure()
            print("Successfully configured Amplify")
        } catch  {
            print("Could not configure Amplify", error)
        }
    }
func uploadFile() {
        let audioUrl = URL(string: "/Users/appaiah/Downloads/RealAudio.mp3")!
        Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(key: fileKey, local: audioUrl){          // let fileKey = "SampleAudio.mp3"
            result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let key):
                print("file with key uploaded \(key)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("failed \(error)")
            }
        }
    }


func downloadFile(){
                    let downloadToFileName = getTermsOfUseURL()     
                    Amplify.Storage.downloadFile(
                        key: fileKey,
                        local: downloadToFileName,
                        progressListener: { progress in
                            print("Progress: \(progress)")
                        }, resultListener: { event in
                            switch event {
                            case .success:
                                print("Completed")
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {  }
                            case .failure(let storageError):
                                print("Failed: \(storageError.errorDescription). \(storageError.recoverySuggestion)")
                            }
                        })
                }
    func getTermsOfUseURL() -> URL {
            let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            print(paths[0].appendingPathComponent(fileKey))
            return paths[0].appendingPathComponent(fileKey)
        }
```